# Can a Ember.Component have both a block and non-block form?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I would like to build an Ember.Component that can be used either in block form, or without a block when some default behavior is desired.

For example, in block form:

```
{{#my-helper}}
  ...
{{/my-helper}}
```

Or non-block form:

```
{{my-helper}}
```

Where the helper template is somehow able to detect that there is not a block and behave accordingly. For example, it would be nice if there was some way to detect the block:

```
{{#if hasBlock}}
  {{yield}}
{{else}}
  default output
{{/if}}
```

For my requirements, I need to have some way to output something only if there's not a block.

Any ideas how to do this?

#### update:

If you're confused by why my question is the same as the accepted answer it's because Ember happened to adopt new syntax that is exactly what I originally imagined up as desirable. When I first asked this question it turned out there was an undocumented way to do this using `{{#if template}}` but that has since been deprecated with Ember 2.x and there's new syntax `{{#if hasBlock}}` which happens to match how I phrased my question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Inside the `Component` you'd want to check the value of `hasBlock`

```
{{#if hasBlock}}
  {{yield}}
{{else}}
  <p>Default content for inline (non-block) form of the component.</p>
{{/if}}
```

Here's a JSBin : http://jsbin.com/IWEKere/1/edit

Comment: It works, but I've never seen this `template` before. Can you link me to the docs?

Comment: I didn't find any documentation about it, just looked at the code.  https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/1f4f6b5b269fe83655733fbfe48d90ba9a8f1c75/packages/ember-views/lib/views/component.js#L111

Comment: I also confirm that this works...accepting. Hopefully this becomes documented and part of the API rather than merely a useful property of the implementation.

Comment: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_component-block-info

Answer (score 2):

The link to the docs is here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_template

The docs don't explicitly say that the template attribute is used in this way. Since the `Ember.Component` class inherits from the `Ember.View` class, it can be inferred that the component template acts like the `Ember.View` layout template.

Answer (score 1):

"template" has been deprecated in favour of partial, eg.

```
{{#if partial}}
  {{yield}}
{{else}}
  <p>Default content for inline (non-block) form of the component.</p>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: As of Ember 1.8.1 it's still `template`.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing `template` directly is currently deprecated, but there is a feature-flagged `hasBlock` property (which basically does `!!template` under the hood) that should be used in this case.

The feature flag is `ember-views-component-block-info`

Here's a link to the merged pull request: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/10461